# Pushing from local to remote repositories using GIT

Tags: git, github

Using GIT, I made some changes in my local repository. Now I want to "upload" changes to remote repository. Does this mean that I will have to create new branch every time to do so? Does this mean, that code in remote depository (which is also accessible via github) must be of "production" quality.

Comment: why would it mean that? You can create branches or just push to master, that's your choice, as well as the quality of your code.

Comment: Absolutely not, that would be ridiculous. You can choose which branch to push at. I think you should try [GitHub's interactive tutorial](https://try.github.io) to get started with Git.

Comment: It means whatever you want it to mean.  If you want to create a new branch every time, do that. If you want to require code push to that repository to be production quality, require that.  Git quite literally could not care less.  You feed git a commit to push and a refname to give it in the remote repo, it sends everything the receiver doesn't have and tells the receiver what refname it should have.  The repo you push to can reject pushes that don't meet whatever standards its administrator likes or respond any other way it wants. That's it. Everything else is arbitrary convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely not, you don't have to. However it is not advisable to push directly to master. The point of version control systems like Git is that you can create different branches and work on them separately and to merge to your main branch (master) only when you're ready to do so.

Imaging this case

> You’ve decided that you’re going to work on issue #53 in whatever
>   issue-tracking system your company uses. To create a branch and switch
>   to it at the same time, you can run the git checkout command with the
>   -b switch: `git checkout -b iss53`. You work on your web site and do some commits. Now you get the call that there is an issue with the web site, and 
>   you need to fix it immediately. With Git, you don’t have to deploy
>   your fix along with the iss53 changes you’ve made, and you don’t have
>   to put a lot of effort into reverting those changes before you can
>   work on applying your fix to what is in production. All you have to do
>   is switch back to your master branch: `git checkout master`. Next, you have a hotfix to make. Let’s create a hotfix branch on which to work until it’s completed: `git checkout -b hotfix`. You can run your tests, make sure the hotfix is what you want, and merge it back into your master branch to deploy to production. You do this with the git merge command: `git checkout master` and `git merge hotfix`. After your super-important fix is deployed, you’re ready to switch back to the work you were doing before you were interrupted.

The quote above is from [this great git resource](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging). It goes in a lot of details and the workflow I'm linking to is what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Git or github do not require a new branch in order for you to push your changes to a remote repository or that the code in the remote repository to be "production" ready.

You may have a workflow that says that you shall do all the work in different (feature, hotfix..) branches and only merge with a merge commit, but that is up to you and your coworkers.